# JCodeModel Create Annotation

Tags: java, jcodemodel

Hi I am relatively new to JCodeModel. I have the follwoing annotation over my class

```
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = com.abc.MyClass.class, name = "MyClass")})
class MyClass {

}
```

How can I create Annotation for the following using JCodeModel.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853943/java-codemodel-annotate-a-method-or-class

Comment: I want to know how to provide array as argument without any name inside the annotation. The sample you shared doesn't showcase an array as parameter of annotation.

Comment: you mean arguments for JCodeModel ?

Comment: Yes, the argument is of type Array. I don't see any such support without mentioning the name of the paramArray.

Comment: Yea. I believe you can't achieve it directly using any constructor. Maybe you could try custom setter and getter methods and converting or casting to array

Answer (score 0):

Just annotate your `JClass`, and to add an array parameter, use the `paramArray()` method:

```
JDefinedClass testClass = codeModel._class("MyClass");

JAnnotationUse jsonSubTypes = testClass.annotate(JsonSubTypes.class);

jsonSubTypes.paramArray("value")
    .annotate(JsonSubTypes.Type.class)
        .param("value", MyClass.class)
        .param("name", "MyClass");
```

Generates:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyClass.class, name = "MyClass")
})
public class MyClass {


}
```